# Movesense DEBUGLOG float value

Tags: movesense

I would like to print float values to the RTT Viewer. 
I tried the DEBUGLOG function but nothing seems to happen.
Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The DEBUGLOG macro uses snprintf internally on the device which does not support float values at the moment. Easiest is to multiply by 10 or 100 and cast to "*int*" and print with "**%d**".